# How to change the display from another class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem which I can't figure out.

I have got two classes:

```
    <div class="left" style="display:block;"></div>
    <div class="leftlarge" style="display:none">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
```

This is what I want:

- `.leftlarge` *onMouseEnter* change `style="display:none`" to `style="display:block"`
- `.left` *onMouseEnter* change `style="display:block"` to `style="display:none"`

I have tried with `css :hover`, but this didn't work. In this way I cannot display the text in that class. I have also applied several javascripts I have found on the internet, but none worked the way I wanted to.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello! When `.leftlarge` is undisplayed, how can `onMouseEnter` have any effect on it?

Comment: That is the question I am trying to ask

Comment: Given that the `displaying` tag has 0 followers, it's not too likely that someone who can answer this question will see it. Add more popular appropriate tags (e.g. language used, html?).

Comment: You cannot do it with CSS hover because when the element is at display:none state there is nothing to hover over :).. so you will have to use another placeholder to overcome this and JS to trigger the evtn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this, but probably without the flicker effect?
http://jsfiddle.net/Ce8PW/2/

```
$(function(){
  $('.left').mouseenter(function(){$('.leftlarge').show();$(this).hide();});
  $('.leftlarge').mouseenter(function(){$('.left').show();$(this).hide();});
});
```

But there must be something in the .left div, at least a `&nbsp;`, or the div won't be displayed at all and you won't be able to attach anything to it.

If you're just after an onmouseover show/hide effect, try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/2ztUp/

If you want to keep displaying the text when the mouse is over it, have the .left div wrap the text div like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hKRPY/

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked, I used your second example and changed in the second line .left to .leftlarge, this stopped the flicker effect.

Comment: I although do have another questions, it does not work in IE with this code:
$(function(){
    $('.left').mouseenter(function(){$('.leftlarge').show();});
    $('.leftlarge').mouseleave(function(){$('.leftlarge').hide();});
});

How could I get it to work in IE?

Comment: With your code, it doesn't work if the mouse never enters the .leftlarge div, because you only hide it on mouseleave. If the mouse never enters, it also never leaves. Otherwise, it works for me in IE9.  

Try this if you can wrap .left around .leftlarge (I changed that in the HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/svajger/3YyDX/   

If you can't, then an *ugly* solution involving a timeout or two would work. Perhaps there's another way, but that is unfortunately the first thing that I could come up with.  

EDIT: SO has some weird edit rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is what u looking for ....!!

Give ID to div,  ('#none_blk') will return true if the object is displayed on the screen otherwise it will return false

```
function isDisplayed(object)
 {
if($(object).css('display') == 'block')
    {
   return true;
     }
   return false;
 }
```

EDIT:

Else you can make use of toggleClass ()